# Can functions be defined by relations?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

So let us say that for whatever reasons, we are not allowed to use function symbols in first-order logic. Then can we define and use a function only by relations?

Comment: I'm sure you can define them as relations. But from what I've gathered the reason to differentiate between the two is to introduce functions as *terms* and relations as *formulas* which help us incredibly in the formulation of our structures/theories. So in First Order Logic I don't think so. But in general many teachers use Relations to define what a function actually is.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you just have to add an axiom stating that the relation is a function:
$$\forall x\forall y\forall z(R(x,y)\land R(x,z)\rightarrow y=z)$$

And you may want to require that the domain is the entire universe.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a function from $A$ to $B$  is a relation between A and B such that any element x of the domain cannot be related to two different element $y$ and $z$ of $B$ ("this is what we mean when we say well defined"). Also every element of the domain $A$ should be related to some element of the target $B$.

In one sentence,every element of the domain should be related to **exactly one** element of the target.

Answer (score 3):

Great Question. Yes! In fact, all functions are relations: the set of all functions is a subset of the set of all relations.

Think about it: take two sets $A = \{a,b,c\},B = \{1,2,3\}$. Create a function between them. Remember the formal definition of a function: a function is just a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, for which we like to say that $x \in X$ is mapped to $y \in Y$. So our function between the two sets $A$ and $B$ will be a subset of the Cartesian product $A \times B$, for example: $f = \{(a,2),(c,1)\}$.

Does that sound familiar to you? That's right. A relation between two sets $A,B$ is always just a subset of the Cartesian product $A \times B$. (Note that here, a *relation* is not the same as an *equivalence relation*, which are much more strict, and you have probably just heard about.)

So far it sounds as if they're the same. So what's the big difference? Well, remember that a function maps each input to just **one** output. You cannot have $f(x) = 5$ and $f(x) = 3$, because then $5=3$. You know this. So for your set that represents a function --- take our example from earlier, $f = \{(a,2),(c,1)\}$ --- we have that for every element of $f$ (an ordered pair $(x,y)$), the first coordinate in the tuple (in this example, that's $x$) is **unique**. That means you cannot have a function like $g = \{(a,2),(c,1),(a,3)\}$ because $a$ appears twice as the first coordinate of a tuple --- it would mean that $g(a) = 2$ and $g(a)=3$, and we can't have that.

And that's the condition that makes the functions a subset of the relations. In a relation, the first coordinate of the tuple does not have to be unique. The relation $R = \{(a,2),(c,1),(a,3)\}$ is perfectly valid. But that set is not a valid function. So even though every function is a relation, not every relation is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Usually functions are defined in the language of set theory. Here is a possible definition using only FOL:

Let $D$ and $C$ be unary predicates. Let $F$ by a binary predicate.

$F$ is said to be a *functional relation* with *domain* predicate $D$ and *codomain* predicate $C$ if and only if:

1. $\forall x,y:[F(x,y)\implies D(x)\land C(y)]$
2. $\forall x:[D(x)\implies \exists y:[F(x,y)]$
3. $\forall x,y_1,y_2:[F(x,y_1)\land F(x,y_2)\implies y_1=y_2]$